# No devices detected with GeForce 310

Tags: xorg

I am trying to get Arch working on an older computer with a GeForce 310. When I run `startx`, I get `No devices detected` (full logs below). The computer is running Ubuntu now, which works fine using nouveau driver. The above tests were on a "persistent live usb" (I installed arch on a usb so I could have a live usb with custom settings and packages). My assumption is that if graphics don't work in the live environment they probably wont work once installed. So I'd like to get it working on the usb before breaking anything.

I have tried with nouveau drivers (xf86-video-nouveau, mesa, and lib32-mesa) and with proprietary drivers (nvidia-340xx-dkms). Same result each time. I assume nouveau should work fine since it works on Ubuntu.

Is there any information I can get off the Ubuntu install to figure out why it works? I poked around `/etc/X11` but I didn't see anything that looked useful to me.

`lspci | grep VGA`:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GT218 [GeForce 310] (rev a2)
```

`Xorg logs`:

```
[    59.231] (WW) Failed to open protocol names file lib/xorg/protocol.txt
[    59.231] 
X.Org X Server 1.20.6
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[    59.231] Build Operating System: Linux Arch Linux
[    59.231] Current Operating System: Linux Portable 5.4.7-arch1-1 #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue, 31 Dec 2019 17:20:16 +0000 x86_64
[    59.231] Kernel command line: \vmlinuz-linux rw root=UUID=a10ccf59-1dff-4f83-b81b-a9912113a42b initrd=initramfs-linux.img
[    59.231] Build Date: 19 December 2019  06:52:37PM
[    59.231]  
[    59.231] Current version of pixman: 0.38.4
[    59.231]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[    59.231] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    59.232] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Fri Jan  3 12:39:17 2020
[    59.232] (==) Using config directory: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    59.232] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    59.232] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[    59.232] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[    59.232] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[    59.232] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[    59.232] (==) No device specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using the first device section listed.
[    59.232] (**) |   |-->Device "Intel Graphics"
[    59.232] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[    59.232] (==) Automatically adding devices
[    59.232] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[    59.232] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[    59.232] (==) Automatically binding GPU devices
[    59.232] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[    59.232] (WW) `fonts.dir' not found (or not valid) in "/usr/share/fonts/misc".
[    59.232]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    59.232]    (Run 'mkfontdir' on "/usr/share/fonts/misc").
[    59.232] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/TTF" does not exist.
[    59.232]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    59.232] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/OTF" does not exist.
[    59.232]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    59.232] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/Type1" does not exist.
[    59.232]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    59.232] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/100dpi,
    /usr/share/fonts/75dpi
[    59.232] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[    59.232] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[    59.232] (II) Module ABI versions:
[    59.232]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[    59.232]    X.Org Video Driver: 24.0
[    59.232]    X.Org XInput driver : 24.1
[    59.232]    X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
[    59.233] (++) using VT number 1

[    59.235] (II) systemd-logind: took control of session /org/freedesktop/login1/session/_31
[    59.236] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[    59.236] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/dri/card0 226:0 fd 10 paused 0
[    59.239] (--) PCI:*(1@0:0:0) 10de:0a66:1462:1837 rev 162, Mem @ 0xfd000000/16777216, 0xc0000000/268435456, 0xd0000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x0000e000/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[    59.240] (WW) Open ACPI failed (/var/run/acpid.socket) (No such file or directory)
[    59.240] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[    59.240] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[    59.241] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    59.241]    compiled for 1.20.6, module version = 1.0.0
[    59.241]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 10.0
[    59.241] (II) LoadModule: "intel"
[    59.241] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so
[    59.241] (II) Module intel: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    59.241]    compiled for 1.20.6, module version = 2.99.917
[    59.241]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    59.241]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0
[    59.241] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Integrated Graphics Chipsets:
    i810, i810-dc100, i810e, i815, i830M, 845G, 854, 852GM/855GM, 865G,
    915G, E7221 (i915), 915GM, 945G, 945GM, 945GME, Pineview GM,
    Pineview G, 965G, G35, 965Q, 946GZ, 965GM, 965GME/GLE, G33, Q35, Q33,
    GM45, 4 Series, G45/G43, Q45/Q43, G41, B43
[    59.242] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) HD Graphics
[    59.242] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Graphics
[    59.242] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Pro Graphics
[    59.242] (EE) No devices detected.
[    59.242] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[    59.242] (EE) no screens found(EE) 
[    59.242] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[    59.242] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[    59.242] (EE) 
[    59.243] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

## Edit:

After explicitly loading the `nouveau` driver like this, I get the below log in `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`:

`/etc/X11/xorg.conf`:

```
Section "Device"
   Identifier   "My Graphics Card"
   Driver       "nouveau"
EndSection
```

```
[   318.800] (WW) Failed to open protocol names file lib/xorg/protocol.txt
[   318.801] 
X.Org X Server 1.20.6
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[   318.803] Build Operating System: Linux Arch Linux
[   318.803] Current Operating System: Linux Portable 5.4.7-arch1-1 #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue, 31 Dec 2019 17:20:16 +0000 x86_64
[   318.803] Kernel command line: \vmlinuz-linux rw root=UUID=a10ccf59-1dff-4f83-b81b-a9912113a42b initrd=initramfs-linux.img
[   318.805] Build Date: 19 December 2019  06:52:37PM
[   318.805]  
[   318.806] Current version of pixman: 0.38.4
[   318.807]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[   318.807] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[   318.810] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Mon Jan  6 15:37:06 2020
[   318.811] (==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
[   318.812] (==) Using config directory: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[   318.813] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[   318.813] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[   318.813] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[   318.813] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[   318.813] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[   318.814] (==) No device specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using the first device section listed.
[   318.814] (**) |   |-->Device "Intel Graphics"
[   318.814] (**) |   |-->GPUDevice "My Graphics Card"
[   318.814] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[   318.814] (==) Automatically adding devices
[   318.814] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[   318.814] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[   318.814] (==) Automatically binding GPU devices
[   318.814] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[   318.814] (WW) `fonts.dir' not found (or not valid) in "/usr/share/fonts/misc".
[   318.814]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   318.814]    (Run 'mkfontdir' on "/usr/share/fonts/misc").
[   318.814] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/TTF" does not exist.
[   318.814]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   318.814] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/OTF" does not exist.
[   318.814]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   318.814] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/Type1" does not exist.
[   318.814]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   318.814] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/100dpi,
    /usr/share/fonts/75dpi
[   318.814] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[   318.814] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[   318.814] (II) Module ABI versions:
[   318.814]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[   318.814]    X.Org Video Driver: 24.0
[   318.814]    X.Org XInput driver : 24.1
[   318.814]    X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
[   318.815] (++) using VT number 1

[   318.818] (II) systemd-logind: took control of session /org/freedesktop/login1/session/_31
[   318.820] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[   318.821] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/dri/card0 226:0 fd 10 paused 0
[   318.830] (--) PCI:*(1@0:0:0) 10de:0a66:1462:1837 rev 162, Mem @ 0xfd000000/16777216, 0xc0000000/268435456, 0xd0000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x0000e000/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[   318.830] (WW) Open ACPI failed (/var/run/acpid.socket) (No such file or directory)
[   318.830] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[   318.831] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[   318.835] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   318.835]    compiled for 1.20.6, module version = 1.0.0
[   318.835]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 10.0
[   318.835] (II) LoadModule: "intel"
[   318.835] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so
[   318.835] (II) Module intel: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   318.835]    compiled for 1.20.6, module version = 2.99.917
[   318.835]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   318.835]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0
[   318.835] (II) LoadModule: "nouveau"
[   318.836] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nouveau_drv.so
[   318.836] (II) Module nouveau: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   318.836]    compiled for 1.20.3, module version = 1.0.16
[   318.836]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   318.836]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0
[   318.836] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Integrated Graphics Chipsets:
    i810, i810-dc100, i810e, i815, i830M, 845G, 854, 852GM/855GM, 865G,
    915G, E7221 (i915), 915GM, 945G, 945GM, 945GME, Pineview GM,
    Pineview G, 965G, G35, 965Q, 946GZ, 965GM, 965GME/GLE, G33, Q35, Q33,
    GM45, 4 Series, G45/G43, Q45/Q43, G41, B43
[   318.837] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) HD Graphics
[   318.837] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Graphics
[   318.837] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Pro Graphics
[   318.837] (II) NOUVEAU driver 
[   318.837] (II) NOUVEAU driver for NVIDIA chipset families :
[   318.837]    RIVA TNT            (NV04)
[   318.837]    RIVA TNT2           (NV05)
[   318.837]    GeForce 256         (NV10)
[   318.837]    GeForce 2           (NV11, NV15)
[   318.837]    GeForce 4MX         (NV17, NV18)
[   318.837]    GeForce 3           (NV20)
[   318.837]    GeForce 4Ti         (NV25, NV28)
[   318.837]    GeForce FX          (NV3x)
[   318.837]    GeForce 6           (NV4x)
[   318.837]    GeForce 7           (G7x)
[   318.837]    GeForce 8           (G8x)
[   318.837]    GeForce 9           (G9x)
[   318.838]    GeForce GTX 2xx/3xx (GT2xx)
[   318.838]    GeForce GTX 4xx/5xx (GFxxx)
[   318.838]    GeForce GTX 6xx/7xx (GKxxx)
[   318.838]    GeForce GTX 9xx     (GMxxx)
[   318.838]    GeForce GTX 10xx    (GPxxx)
[   318.838] (II) [drm] nouveau interface version: 1.3.1
[   318.838] (EE) No devices detected.
[   318.838] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[   318.838] (EE) no screens found(EE) 
[   318.838] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[   318.838] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[   318.838] (EE) 
[   318.840] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

The nouveau driver is definitly loading but it's still not finding my graphics card.

Comment: Xorg finds a `Device "Intel Graphics"`. Can you disable the Intel graphics via the BIOS or create a `xorg.conf` which explicitly loads the nouveau driver?

Comment: That makes no sense to me. It's an AMD machine... I will try what you suggest.